# How to use hashtags in Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, tags, productivity

I want to be able to use hashtags in Gmail - e.g. add **#important** in certain emails I send to myself or others, and be able to A) search on that specific tag and B) filter emails with that tag so that they automatically get processed in a certain way, like adding a label.

The problem is that when searching gmail, if you type "#important" (with or without quotes), you get *every* email with the word "important", whether it's preceded by a hash or not, which makes the tag pretty useless.

Same deal for the filters- if I set up a filter where email has the word "#important", it gets triggered for the word "important", not just the hashtag.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31323/186085

Comment: Note also that a "_hashtag_" isn't really a concept that exists in many text-based systems (such as email)... It's a special feature of certain social media platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like special chars are not recognized by Gmail search. (Re your comment, the hashtag concept exists for ALL text-based systems - it's literally nothing more than a word with a pound sign in front of it, meant to aid search.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't search for special characters in Gmail: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31323/186085 (thanks to @Attie for link)

Nor can you search/filter using regex, which is a major bummer.

My solution ended up being to use underscore-prefixed tags, instead of hash-prefixed tags. Gmail recognizes underscores, so it seems to work pretty well.

e.g. use **_important** instead of **#important**. You can now search/filter on "_important", which will NOT include "important" in results.

**Additional resources:**
- [Gmail Labeler](https://github.com/paoloantinori/gmail-labeler) - Allows you to "Label and filter Gmail threads using basic RegEx against the email body or headers", though haven't tried it.